# Is it possible to break Python Tornado's urls into multiple files?

Tags: python, tornado

I want to know if it's possible to break url files into multiple files. currently my URL file is like this:

```
url_patterns = {
    (r'/web/([^/]+)/', IndexHandler),
    (r'/web/([^/]+)/test', IndexTestDic),
    (r'/web/([^/]+)/category/([^/]+)', CategoryHandler),
    (r'/web/([^/]+)/channel', ChannelHandler),
    (r'/web/([^/]+)/savechannel', savechannel),
}
```

is it possible to have something like this:

```
#in url1.py
url_patterns1 = {
    (r'/web/([^/]+)/', IndexHandler),
    (r'/web/([^/]+)/test', IndexTestDic)
}

#url2.py
url_patterns2 = {
    (r'/web/([^/]+)/category/([^/]+)', CategoryHandler),
    (r'/web/([^/]+)/channel', ChannelHandler),
    (r'/web/([^/]+)/savechannel', savechannel),
}
```

Comment: `{a, b, c}` is set notation. Order matters here, so use a list instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can break them.

```
url_patterns1 = [
    (r'/web/([^/]+)/', IndexHandler),
    (r'/web/([^/]+)/test', IndexTestDic)
]

url_patterns2 = [
    (r'/web/([^/]+)/category/([^/]+)', CategoryHandler),
    (r'/web/([^/]+)/channel', ChannelHandler),
    (r'/web/([^/]+)/savechannel', savechannel),
]
```

then finally:

```
url_patterns1.extend(url_patterns2)
```

Now you have them all in url_patterns1 variable.

**Note:** As mentioned by others, it'll be better to use list `[]` instead of set `{}` in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what is this structure? It's not similar to lists and dictionaries. so what is it?

Comment: This is list of tuples. Each element of the list `url_patterns1` is a tuple. Learn more about tuples here: https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

Comment: Not a syntax error, but a shorthand for `set`, which are unordered so are not recommended in this case! (Blender also said this in top level comments)